# Java generics warning requiring guru meditation

Tags: java, android, generics, warnings, aide-ide

I have some Java code like the following snippet (the example is simplified from the original code). A yellow squiggle and warning message appear, as indicated by the code comment below. The message is: "This method invocation is unsafe since the passed arguments may be of a wrong type."

```
abstract class Seek<T> {
    abstract <S> Seek<S> seek(S... o);
    abstract <T2> void map(Func<T,T2> call);
    interface Func<I,O> {
        public O call(I x);
    }
    public <X2> void go(Func<T,X2> c, T some) {
        seek(some).map(c); // <- yellow squiggle here on 'c'
    }
}
```

Why does the warning appear? What is the best way to fix this?

Note:
I'm using the AIDE development environment for Android.

EDIT: I fixed an error in the code after reading the answer from @tsolakp and @LouisWasserman.

Comment: I would have thought this has something to do with the generic array creation on `seek(S...)`. Can you make `seek` take a `List<S>` instead?

Comment: Based on your method signatures, `T`, `T2` and `X2` are all superfluous.

Comment: The warning message from AIDE is misleading. When I compile your code with the command-line compiler (version 1.8.0_112), I don't get a warning for `c` on the line you indicated. Instead, I get a warning on the declaration of `seek` about "Possible heap pollution from parameterized vararg type S" and a second warning in the call to `seek` about "unchecked generic array creation for varargs parameter of type X1[]".

Comment: @TedHopp, thanks I thought maybe it's something like that. AIDE can be a little /loose/ with its warning explanations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually there are three warnings in that code:

1. > Type safety: Potential heap pollution via varargs parameter o
   >   at `abstract <S> Seek<S> seek(S... o);`
2. > The type parameter T is hiding the type T at `abstract <T,T2> void map(Func<T,T2> call);`
3. > Type safety: A generic array of X1 is created for a varargs parameter at `seek(some).map(c);`

It can be clean of warnings 
A. take out varargs parameter from generic like:

```
abstract class Seek<T> {
   abstract <S> Seek<S> seek(S o); // <- no more yellow squiggle
   abstract <T1,T2> void map(Func<T1,T2> call); // <- no more yellow squiggle
   interface Func<I,O> {
      public O call(I x);
   }
   public <X1,X2> void go(Func<X1,X2> c, X1 some) {
      seek(some).map(c); // <- no more yellow squiggle here on 'c'
   }
 }
```

B. define arrays explicitly like:

```
  abstract class Seek<T> {
  abstract <S> Seek<S> seek(S[] o);        // <- no more yellow squiggle
  abstract <T2> void map(Func<T,T2> call); // <- no more yellow squiggle
  interface Func<I,O> {
    public O call(I x);
  }
  public <X1,X2> void go(Func<X1,X2> c, X1[] some) {
    seek(some).map(c); // <- no more yellow squiggle
  }
}
```

but,  `S[] o` is quite not the same as `S... o`.  It can take only Array explicitly. Maybe you need to reconsider your design?

IMHO: I really do not understand needs to have that many Generic type parameters at the same time on class and methods level...

Comment: I tried this and it worked! Thanks! I didn't realise `varargs` was so different to passing a solid array.

Comment: BTW, the real code is much bigger than that given, I just wanted to reduce it down while still keeping the original warning.

Comment: Understood... but usually I use Generic for the class (i.e. `Seek<T>`) when number of implementations has to deal with different actual classes. While on the method level (i.e. `public <X1,X2> void go(Func<X1,X2> c, X1 some)`) is more likely for utility kind of methods when containing class may not be even abstract or generic... But it is matter of taste... :-)

Comment: Actually most of the `generics` complexity above comes from using the TotallyLazy functional library. Take a look at its `Sequences.sequence(T...)` method.

Answer (score 1):

`map` should only have `T2` as a type parameter, not `T`.  Right now the `T` shadows the `T` from the `Seek<T>` class, that is, you have two type variables named T that are actually different, and you don't want that.

Comment: Thanks I didn't understand this at first, but you're correct. I've updated the question, however this change doesn't fix the warning... of course.

Answer (score 0):

The warnings I get from compiling your code are related to the generic array creation from the `seek(S...)` method.

If you can change this to be a `List<S>`, you can invoke it using `Arrays.asList()`:

```
abstract class Seek<T> {
    abstract <S> Seek<S> seek(List<S> o);

    // ...

    public <X1,X2> void go(Func<X1,X2> c, X1 some) {
        seek(Arrays.asList(some)).map(c);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I've just tried this and still get the same warning.

Answer (score 0):

Change `T` to `T1` in the `map` method. 
You will also get generic array warning too. Here is modified version with no warnings:

```
abstract static class Seek<T> {

    abstract <S> Seek<S> seek(List<S> s);

    abstract <T1,T2> void map(Func<T1, T2> call);

    interface Func<I,O> {
        public O call(I x);
    }

    public <X1,X2> void go(Func<X1,X2> c, X1 some) {
        seek( Arrays.asList(some) ).map(c); 
    }
}
```

After some comments it appers that OP might have intended to make `map` method to be bound with `Seek` class generic type. If thats the case we can use this solution, as suggested by @Louis Wasserman and @Andy Turner:

```
abstract static class Seek<T> {

    abstract <S> Seek<S> seek(List<S> s);

    abstract <T2> void map(Func<T, T2> call);

    interface Func<I,O> {
        public O call(I x);
    }

    public <X1,X2> void go(Func<X1,X2> c, X1 some) {
        seek( Arrays.asList(some) ).map(c); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Changing `T` to `T1` has no effect. It's just replacing one arbitrary name with another.

Comment: Wrong. His `map` takes `Func` that has two generic parameters. Therefore it needs to either declare two generic parameters in `map` signature or just use `Seek`'s  generic type. Since OP did not mention what is expected I assume map needs not use  `Seek`'s  generic type.

Comment: Yep, but declaring `<T, T2>` on the method declares a new type variable `T` which shadows the one on the class.

Comment: Thats why it needs to be change to something else like `T1`. Since second parameter is `T2` I assume the `map` method does not need to be bound by class level `T`.

Comment: Changing `T` to `T1` doesn't actually change the warnings produced by the compiler.

Comment: It does. The next warning is about generic varargs.

Comment: Thanks for updating your answer. I have tried your suggestion but now get a similar warning for `Arrays.asList(some)`. It says "Passing this argument is unsafe because an instance of type 'java.util.List' may not be of type 'java.util.List<S?>'."